# How about a tag pointing to the respective Wikipedia article or a modified version thereof?

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-wiki

Rather than having your own wiki, why not connect it to **Wikipedia** and create a deep collaboration? So when I type *CMake*, for illustration, I go to an article on wikipedia or a modified version like the collaboration between facebook and wikipedia. (If your click on your city name you get the introduction article of wikipedia corresponding to that city.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Our tag wikis are for frequently asked questions, book lists, and a bit of general knowledge. Wikipedia doesn't do that.

Check out the [PHP tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info). Will any Wikipedia page do that? No. They may have a list of resources, but they won't have a FAQ section.

I don't see much of a benefit here, we're just making it worse if we add that.